# Is it possible to perform loadtesting on thick client Excel 2007

Tags: loadrunner

We are planning to do a load test on thick client Excel 2007 using HP Load Runner 11.0.Excel application has got macros enabled and has got web services running in the back end to communicate with the server.

Is it possible to do Load test.

Also when we tried recording excel 2007 using vugen, events were not recorded and found that this requires a patch from HP. If some one has got patch and are able to do it, please let me know.

Any timely help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One: You are engaging in software piracy when you ask for a cracked patch.  If you are legitimately able to have access to the patches because of a maintenance agreement then you can simply download the patches yourself.

That comment about the cracked patch has made me personally far less likely to assist you completely.

Two: I will say, "Yes" it is possible.   I will not give you the steps but assuming you have skills with the tool and the foundations skills required by the profession you will be able to figure this out.

Three: LoadRunner has been able to record HTTP conversations, the communication foundation for web services, via proxy wince LoadRunner version 5.02, which was available in 1998.  That capability is retained even in the most current release. That is going to be your key.

Four: Because you operate in the cracked software universe which is a stain on the whole performance testing profession you do not get the explicit steps that may well have been provided.   Good luck to you on this issue and may your next software audit go well.

Don't be a crack head.  It has long term career and social consequences.   You are introducing substantial financial risk into a profession designed from the outset to identify, eliminate, manage and control risks.   Your behavior is running counter to your profession

Comment: Thanks for the help James. When I meant crack does not mean Iam trying to crack the software or am asking help if some one has done it. We were in the process of evaluating whether LR 11.0 can go well with Excel 2007. Apologies if I sounded unprofessional with the word crack.

Comment: As you are evaluating please turn your questions to your VAR or HP Systems engineer.  Assuming you are involved in a legitimate pre-purchase evaluation of LoadRunner, the SE can provide any patch you need to complete your evaluation prior to purchase.  Changing your original post to remove the reference to the cracked patch does not alter your intended behavior, it was quite transparent in nature.     What you want to do requires no patch to the software but it does require someone who knows the software, such as your VAR or HP SE who is assisting with your evaluation. Good day to you.